# How to change default file watch options in LiteServer

Tags: html, server, lite-server

So I'm trying to use LiteServer in my project, but I can't get it to change the default watch of `index.html`, my current file is `index1.html`. I specified `app2.js` as the entry point during `npm init`, so I was able to change the JS default, but not for HTML.

```
> lite-server

Did not detect a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` override file. Using lite-server defaults...
** browser-sync config **
{ injectChanges: false,
  files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
  watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
  server: { baseDir: './', middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ] } }
[BS] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://10.40.244.189:3000
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://10.40.244.189:3001
 --------------------------------------
[BS] Serving files from: ./
[BS] Watching files...
16.12.21 18:43:32 200 GET /index.html
16.12.21 18:43:32 200 GET /style.css
16.12.21 18:43:33 200 GET /app2.js
16.12.21 18:43:34 404 GET /favicon.ico
```

I know the [doc](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server) mentions the use of a `bs-config.json` file, but I couldn't get any reference which has the syntax for this.

Would appreciate the help!

---

UPDATE - I currently have this in the `bs-config.json` file, but no use -

```
{
  "files": ["style.css", "app2.js", "index1.html"]
}
```

Comment: Never mind, I just added `/index1.html` to the route, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

lite-server is based on BrowserSync.  bs-config.js is browsersync's config file.  The config options are documented here:
https://browsersync.io/docs/options

For example, to set your default indx to be index1.html, instead of setting it in your routes, the bs-config.json could contain:

```
{
  "server": {
    "baseDir": "src",
    "index": "/index1.html",
    "routes": {
      "/node_modules": "node_modules"
    }
  }
}
```